# double quotes chars, split_string and maplist a fact fails but works on repl

Tags: prolog

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

initial_fen("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1").

fen_board(Fen, B) :-
   split_string(Fen, " ", "",
         [Pieses, Turn, Castles, EnPassant, _, _]),
   split_string(Pieses, "/", "", _Ranks),
   maplist(rank_pieses, _Ranks, B).


rank_pieses([Char|Rest], [Char]).
```

`?- initial_fen(Fen), fen_board(Fen, B).` fails at,

`rank_pieses("rnbqkbnr", _23424).` step when I trace.

I don't understand because on prolog repl, if I ask for:

`?- rank_pieses("rnbqkbnr", Ls).` , it returns `Ls = [r].`

Comment: Seems this is SWI. The 4th argument of `split_string/4` is always a (SWI-specific) string which does not unify with `[_|_]`.

Comment: `split_string([a],"","",R),R=[[_|_]].`

Answer (score 0):

I removed `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`

And changed the definition to:

```
rank_pieses(Ranks, [Char]) :- string_chars(Ranks, [Char|_]).
```

Now it works.
I don't know the reasoning here though.